# Can someone tell me why this icon appears next to my database?

Tags: phpmyadmin

[image]

Hello, can anybody tell me why this particular database has this 'toolbox' icon next to it?  In case you don't know where this item exists, it's on the left pane when you open phpmyadmin, where all the databases reside.

I don't believe I did anything different or special when I created it.  Note: even the text 'songfarm' is italicized.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

That's the icon used when databases are grouped together. If you click the plus sign `+` in front of that icon, you should see the other database(s) expand there. By default, anything with an underscore `_` is used as the separator when creating groups; so you might have databases `songfarm_1`, `songfarm_devel`, and `songfarm_primary` which would all group under the `songfarm` prefix like in your picture.

You can [disable this feature](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_NavigationTreeEnableGrouping) entirely with `$cfg['NavigationTreeEnableGrouping'] = false;` or [change the separator](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_NavigationTreeDbSeparator) (like`$cfg['NavigationTreeDbSeparator'] = '|'`). A different configuration option [affects table names](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_NavigationTreeTableSeparator) similarly (`$cfg['NavigationTreeDbSeparator'] = '||';`.